# Excel date - 8/11/2015 6:50:22.000 = 8/11/2015 6:50:22.000 = FALSE? What is happening here?

Tags: excel, datetime, julian-date

I have data from two sources that I am trying to match on date/time. The problem is that I do not get a match. So I converted the date/time to Julian and encountered something odd.

```
8/11/2015 6:50:22.000   42227.2849768518
8/11/2015 6:50:22.000   42227.2849768519
```

I have never seen this before and I do not know how it is happening. The only thing that I can think is that the date/time, as originally created and entered into the source excel files was accurate out to that digit? If that is the case, how do I make excel act like the two values are the same? Do I need to convert all of the Date/Time values to Number and strip off that tenth digit to the right and limit the values to nine digits to the right? How many digits do I need to store in order to maintain accuracy to the second?

Comment: You forgot about milliseconds.

Comment: *Conversion* to number isn't necessary, BTW. DateTime values in Excel are actually just floating point numbers with formatting applied. The integer portion of the number is the days since 1/1/1900, and the decimal portion is the fractional parts of a day (1 second = 1 day / 24 * 60 * 60, or 1/86400). So you can just use them as numbers already without any conversion, and check the difference between them to see if it's within an acceptable difference in order to determine equality.

Answer (score 0):

The third decimal place represents an accuracy of 1.15741e-8 days, so if the ABSOLUTE VALUE of the difference between it and the compared value is smaller than 5.78705e-9, then that's within your accuracy requirements.

something like

```
=ABS(time1 - time2) < 5.78705e-9
```

should do the trick, returning TRUE if the two values are considered 'close enough to be classed as the same for my purposes' and FALSE if they are distinct enough.